# How to resolve TypeError ('expected ' + str(expected_type)) TypeError: expected <class 'float'> (Openpyxl 3.1.1)

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

Is there a way I can resolve this type error when reading data with openpyxl from my source workbooks? I am only trying to extract values, not underlying formulas. I have tried to use the following to convert all instances of "-" with 0 to try and resolve the issue with this line (updated):

```
source_row_data = [float(col_value) if col_value != "-" else 0 for col_value in source_row_data]
```

Is this the correct approach? Is the fact that the data is in a pivot table causing complications? Here is the error:

```
File "C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 59, in _convert  
    value = expected_type(value)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kyle\DEV\Satori\Attribution Analysis\UpdatePortfolio.py", line 37, in <module>
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(wb_name, data_only=True)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 346, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 301, in read
    self.read_worksheets()
  File "C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 278, in read_worksheets
    pivot.cache = self.parser.pivot_caches[pivot.cacheId]
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\workbook.py", line 131, in pivot_caches
    records = get_rel(self.archive, cache.deps, cache.id, RecordList)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\packaging\relationship.py", line 163, in get_rel
    obj = cls.from_tree(tree)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 87, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 87, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\pivot\fields.py", line 147, in __init__
    self.v = v
    ^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 71, in __set__
    value = _convert(self.expected_type, value)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 61, in _convert
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'float'>



import openpyxl
import calendar


# Open the destination workbook
try:
    dest_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Liquid Portfolio Attribution Analysis - Blank.xlsx')
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
    print("Error occurred in cell:", e.cell.coordinate)
    print("Cell value:", e.cell.value)    

# Define the destination sheet and the starting row
dest_sheet = dest_wb['Data']

def get_maximum_rows(*, sheet_object):
    rows = 0
    for max_row, row in enumerate(sheet_object, 1):
        if not all(col.value is None for col in row):
            rows += 1
    return rows

# Get the maximum row with data in the destination sheet
dest_last_row = get_maximum_rows(sheet_object=dest_sheet)

# Set the starting row for copying data in the destination sheet
if dest_last_row == 4:
    dest_row = 5
else:
    dest_row = dest_last_row + 1

# Loop through each set of workbooks
for month in ['04']:
    for alpha in ['I', 'II']:
        # Open the source workbook
        wb_name = f'Copy of 2022-{month} Alpha {alpha} - Workbook.xlsx'
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(wb_name, data_only=True)

        # Get the PCAP sheet
        sheet_name = f'2022-{month} PCAP (R)'
        sheet = wb[sheet_name]

        # Copy the data and paste it into the destination sheet

        # Add the date to column B
        last_day = calendar.monthrange(2022, int(month))[1]
        date_str = f'{int(month)}/{last_day}/2022'
        dest_sheet[f'B{dest_row+1}'].value = date_str

        #Create dictionary with key value pairs to map source columns to destination columns
        data_map = {'A': 'C', 'B': 'E', 'D': 'F', 'F': 'G', 'H': 'H', 'U': 'J', 'AI': 'I', 'AO': 'K'}

        #Determines the last row to copy based on the max number of rows between the source and dest sheets
        last_row = sheet.max_row - 1
        print(f"Source sheet last row: {sheet.max_row}")
        print(f"Destination row: {dest_row}")

        
        for row in range(6, last_row + 1):
            dest_row +=1

            source_row_data = [col.value for col in sheet[f'A{row}:AO{row}'][0]] #Creates a list of values for each column in the current row of source sheet
            source_row_data = [float(col_value) if col_value != "-" else 0 for col_value in source_row_data] #Check if there are formulas returning "-" i.e. 0
            print(source_row_data)
            
            if any(col_value is not None for col_value in source_row_data):
                for source_col, dest_col in data_map.items(): #Iterates through items in data_map dictionary
                    if len(source_col) == 1:
                        source_col_val = source_row_data[ord(source_col) - 65]  
                    else:
                        # Treat the column as a special case and manually convert it to the corresponding column number
                        col_num = (ord(source_col[0]) - 64) * 26 + (ord(source_col[1]) - 65)
                        source_col_val = source_row_data[col_num - 1]

                    #Sets dest_col_val to the cell in the destination sheet corr. to current dest column being iterated over and current row
                    dest_col_val = dest_sheet[f'{dest_col}{dest_row}'] 
                    if source_col in ['H', 'U', 'AI'] and row == last_row:
                        dest_col_val.value = None
                    else:
                        dest_col_val.value = source_col_val
                #print(f"Source column length: {len(source_col)}")
            else:
                print(f'Row {row} has blank data')

        wb.close()

dest_wb.save('Liquid Portfolio Attribution Analysis - Copy 2.xlsx')
```

[image: Source Workbook]

Comment: When adding Tracebacks you should include all the text from 'Traceback' to the last line. And format it as code to make it easier to read. The dash conversion looks OK so cannot comment on why there is an issue and the truncated error text provided doesn't help to make it clearer

Comment: @moken Thank you for the clarification. I have updated with the full error message.

Comment: From your details and the traceback; the issue is occurring when you open one (all) of the files like '2022-04 Alpha I - Workbook.xlsx' being imported into the single workbook. Since this is an error when Openpyxl opens the workbook the conversion of '-' to '0' will not change the error since that is something you are doing after the sheet is opened (and saving to a different name). Do you concur or did I miss something? Since the error occurs while reading the file the issue is with whatever is creating the file? I assume you can open the file(s) in Excel and resave to clear the error??

Comment: @moken Yes - You are right that it is an issue of when Openpyxl opens the source workbooks. I was incorrect that it has to do with the instances of formulas returning 0 in the format "-". When I open the files, and copy and paste the entire sheet as values, I still receive the same error. I can copy and paste the sheet into a new workbook, but that defeats the purpose of trying to automate the process. Could it have to do w/ external links in the wb the script is not able to read? I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "the issue is  w/ whatever is creating the file." Does this help at all? TY

Comment: I mean the issue is in the file ('2022-04 Alpha I - Workbook.xlsx') so presumably whoever or whatever is creating the file is causing the issue in these files. As you note and converting your image to excel data does not result reproduce this error so its difficult to determine why the error occurs. Therefore you may need to investigate how these values are entered into the sheet to see if the reason can be determined and/or avoided. At this point, the origin could be anything including external data links.

Comment: From the traceback, the error is related to a pivot table.

Comment: @CharlieClark I have removed my data from a table (Design Tab -> Convert to Range) but have not resolved the error yet.